# Imagick is not working inside php CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, imagick

Imagick extension works perfectly on the simple PHP code but not inside the CodeIgniter. What could be the possible issue, kindly guide?

I have tried the code of ColorizeImage

```
function colorizeImage($imagePath, $color, $opacity) {
$imagick = new \Imagick(realpath($imagePath));
$opacity = $opacity / 255.0;
$opacityColor = new \ImagickPixel("rgba(0, 0, 0, $opacity)");
$imagick->colorizeImage($color, $opacityColor);
header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
echo $imagick->getImageBlob();
}
echo colorizeImage('D:/download.png', 'green','50');
```

View Page:

```
      <body>
      <label>Input Image</label>
      <form method="post" id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type='file' name="userfile" size="20" onchange="readURL(this);"/>
      </div>
      <label>Orignal Image</label><br>
      <img id="blah" src="#" alt="" />
      <label>Colorized Image </label>
      <div id="result">
      </div>
    </div>
      <input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload" value="Apply" class="btn btn-info" />
      </form>   
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#upload_form').on('submit', function(e){  
       e.preventDefault();  
       if($('#userfile').val() == '')  
       {  
            alert("Please Select the File");  
       }  
       else  
       {  
            $.ajax({  
                 url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>Equalize/equalize_image",   
                 //base_url() = http://localhost/tutorial/codeigniter  
                 method:"POST",  
                 data:new FormData(this),  
                 contentType: false,  
                 cache: false,  
                 processData:false,  
                 success:function(data)  
                 {  
                      $('#result').html(data);



                 }  
            });  
       }  
       });  
    });  
  </script>
  </body>
```

without CI: it gives me perfect result, but with CI it gives following result:

�PNG  IHDR2����gAMA���a cHRMz&�����u0�`:�p��Q<��PLTE��������������������޾�ٱ�׮�ժ�ӣ�͛�ǖ�Ð��������{����tx�pt����lp�hl�cg�y}�[_����w{�sw�vx����W[�TX�MQ�|����HL�@D�dg�rw�EI����9>�qu�os�38��� ������CCC���yyy������TTT���)))���&&&���nnn������;;;mp�```iii�����ػ�����YYY???di���BbKGD�H pHYs���+tIME�7��/%5IDATx��ic�:ӆm6�=6�H ����R�4m�4}���Ϋ�l���-;�$}3�҂�.�n�F��|؇}؇}Xf���F,�������N��g>����T����LB�Q+��̬B�J�V�U��?��N ����j��^t��A���܈��F�٬�zN����"N%$@��!s�5��l676땭

How to add the imagick extension to CodeIgniter(CI) (if that is the problem ) so that it can work in CI?

Comment: Not sending your image headers? Has nothing to with the 'extension', its code level. Header / output buffer...

Comment: how to provide image headers? I thought imagick don't need to?

Comment: Well you are echoing an image, then a binary true? No, imagick does not send headers to the web browser. - `getimageBlob()`... "Returns a string containing the image. ". You are sending this to browser, not trying to update a file? If so use: 
`header('Content-Type: image/png');`

Comment: Again it gives same output. The code provided above gives this output only inside CodeIgniter.

Comment: codeigniter is just a php framework, it doesn't modify third-party or native classes/functions. if this code works outside of CI then the only explanation is user error

Comment: I have asked the same, what could be the error that cause this program to not work inside CI

Comment: @Alex please answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51507898/how-to-pass-image-from-controller-to-view-with-codeigniter-imagick

Comment: looks like the same exact issue as youve had before and was fixed

Comment: but now image is equalized and uploaded but not printing in view, please fix?

Answer (score 1):

I think your workaround might be "die();" function after echo();

```
    function colorizeImage($imagePath, $color, $opacity) {
$imagick = new \Imagick(realpath($imagePath));
$opacity = $opacity / 255.0;
$opacityColor = new \ImagickPixel("rgba(0, 0, 0, $opacity)");
$imagick->colorizeImage($color, $opacityColor);
header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
echo $imagick->getImageBlob();
}
echo colorizeImage('D:/download.png', 'green','50');
die;
```

But better to send headers with the help of CodeIgniter.

I think CodeIgniter is using buffer (ob_start), then sends default headers which are text/html and you get the text instead of image. Just don't use "echo" return a response and add correct headers. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/output.html

Your code should return binary image file. So you cannot surround it with anything. 
If it's inside the action of the controller, then this action should return only this image with the correct headers and nothing else. And it should not be in view.

Comment: Tried everything, problem is when I fetch the data in view page on a click action, it shows me text instead of page. But, when I run controller page my self like 'Colorize/colorize_image' it shows me correct output that is colorized image. Now what is the problem? I have edited the code and added view page text.