# how to pass image from controller to view with CodeIgniter Imagick

Tags: php, codeigniter, imagick

I was working with CodeIgniter php, and using Imagick for some image manipulation. Now I want to upload image and after image manipulation e.g Image equalizing, I want to pass or load the equalized image from controller to view. The image is equalized and uploaded to a path, but I am unable to load the output equalized image to view page. So, kindly guide how to handle this problem?

Controller Code:

```
class Equalize extends CI_Controller { 

    public function equalize_image() { 

        if (isset($_FILES["userfile"])) {

            $tmpFile = $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"];
            $ext = pathinfo($_FILES["userfile"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $fileName = uniqid(rand(), true) . "." . $ext;
            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($tmpFile);
            if ($width == null && $height == null) {
            header("Location: index.php");
            return;
        }
        $image = new Imagick($tmpFile);
        $image->equalizeImage();
        $image->writeImage(FCPATH.'/assets/images' . "/" . $fileName);
        header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
        echo $image;    
    }

  }
}
```

View Code:

```
<label>Input Image</label>
      <form method="post" id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type='file' name="userfile" size="20" onchange="readURL(this);"/>
      <label>Orignal Image</label><br>
      <img id="blah" src="#" alt="" />
      <label>Equalized Image </label>
      <div id="result">
      </div>
      <input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload" value="Apply" class="btn btn-info" />
      </form>   
<script>
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah')
                .attr('src', e.target.result)
                .width(200)
                .height(200);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
 $(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#upload_form').on('submit', function(e){  
       e.preventDefault();  
       if($('#userfile').val() == '')  
       {  
            alert("Please Select the File");  
       }  
       else  
       {  
            $.ajax({  
                 url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>Equalize/equalize_image",   
                 //base_url() = http://localhost/tutorial/codeigniter  
                 method:"POST",  
                 data:new FormData(this),  
                 contentType: false,  
                 cache: false,  
                 processData:false,  
                 success:function(data)  
                 {  
                      $('#result').html(data);



                 }  
            });  
       }  
  });  
  });  
</script>
</body>
```

With this code I am facing this output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrSKN.jpg. How to load the image in view?

Comment: Have you checked the response of your async call? You're setting an image content type, but you're using the `view()` method of codeigniter. It's probably better to return an image path and add a `img` tag to the DOM

Comment: Kindly tell the code for returning path, I am stuck in this?

Answer (score 1):

## Take 1

Just pass the newly created image url to the ajax success function via json and modify the img src to that url.

HTML:

```
<label>Input Image</label>
<form method="post" id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='file' name="userfile" size="20" onchange="readURL(this);"/>
    <label>Orignal Image</label><br>
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="" />
    <label>Equalized Image </label>
    <div id="result">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x400">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload" value="Apply" class="btn btn-info" />
</form>   
<script>
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah')
                        .attr('src', e.target.result)
                        .width(200)
                        .height(200);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#upload_form').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($('#userfile').val() == '')
            {
                alert("Please Select the File");
            } else
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Equalize/equalize_image",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: new FormData(this),
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        if (data.success == true) {
                            $('#result').find('img').attr('src', data.file);
                        } else {
                            alert(data.msg);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
```

PHP:

```
try {
    if (!isset($_FILES["userfile"])) {
        throw new Exception('No file uploaded.');
    }
    $tmpFile = $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"];
    $ext = pathinfo($_FILES["userfile"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $fileName = uniqid(rand(), true) . "." . $ext;
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($tmpFile);
    if ($width == null && $height == null) {
        throw new Exception('An error occured.');
    }
    $image = new Imagick($tmpFile);
    $new_file = "assets/images/{$fileName}";
    $image->equalizeImage();
    $image->writeImage(FCPATH . '/' . $new_file);
    echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'file' => base_url($new_file)));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 'msg' => $e->getMessage()));
}
```

---

## Take 2

This is the only way you can download the file without having it saved on the server.

```
class Test extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('test');
    }

    public function eq() {
        try {
            if (!isset($_FILES['userfile'])) {
                throw new Exception('No file uploaded.');
            }
            $file_error = $_FILES['userfile']['error'];
            if ($file_error !== 0) {
                throw new Exception('Error uploading: Code ' . $file_error);
            }
            $tmp_file = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($tmp_file);
            if ($width == null && $height == null) {
                throw new Exception('An error occured.');
            }
            $image = new Imagick($tmp_file);
            $image->equalizeImage();
            $encoded_file = base64_encode($image->getimageblob());
            echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'type' => $image->getimageformat(), 'file' => $encoded_file));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 'msg' => $e->getMessage()));
        }
    }

    public function download() {
        $contents = $this->input->post('image_contents');
        $extension = $this->input->post('extension');
        if (is_null($contents) || is_null($extension)) {
            show_error('Image contents empty');
        }
        $name = 'equalized_image.' . strtolower($extension);
        $contents = base64_decode($contents);
        $this->load->helper('download');
        force_download($name, $contents);
    }

}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function readURL(input) {
                if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        $('#original-image')
                                .attr('src', e.target.result);
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                }
            }
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#download').hide();
                $('#upload_form').on('submit', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if ($('#userfile').val() == '')
                    {
                        alert("Please Select the File");
                    } else
                    {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/neou_cms/test/eq",
                            method: "POST",
                            data: new FormData(this),
                            contentType: false,
                            cache: false,
                            processData: false,
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function (data)
                            {
                                console.log(data);
                                if (data.success == true) {
                                    var image_content = 'data:image/' + data.type + ';base64,' + data.file;
                                    $('#eq-image').attr('src', image_content);
                                    $('#image_contents').attr('value', data.file);
                                    $('#extension').attr('value', data.type);
                                    $('#download').show();
                                } else {
                                    alert(data.msg);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

            });
        </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" onchange="readURL(this);"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Original Image</td>
                    <td>Equalized Image</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img id="original-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x400" width="300" height="auto">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <img id="eq-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x400" width="300" height="auto">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload" value="Apply" class="btn btn-info">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>  
        </form>
        <form method="post" action="/neou_cms/test/download">
            <input type="hidden" value="" name="image_contents" id="image_contents">
            <input type="hidden" value="" name="extension" id="extension">
            <input type="submit" name="download" id="download" value="Download Image">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did this answer your **current** question? If so I would appreciate an upvote and or acceptance for the effort. Comments aren't for posing new questions.

Comment: Thanks Alex but I wanted to pass it in PHP array value for download purose.

Comment: Then why are you using ajax. And why is your problem statement "The image is equalized and uploaded to a path, but I am unable to load the output equalized image to view page".... That implies exactly why my answer addresses the image output is populated in the browser

Comment: You are right but I don't know how to create download link for this image displaying through ajax that is why said so

Comment: Because you can download through ajax that's not how it works. It's just a means of getting and receiving data, not redirecting to a page where you can force a download.

Comment: So what should I do now?

Comment: Scripts, like ajax, can't download. The security risks would be immense. You should really research Ajax and jquery a bit more as it seems like you don't fully grasp it.

Comment: is there any way to pass the image to other page for download purpose?

Comment: Well from a design standpoint the easiest way would be to send in the json array a file path and then add that path to a button on the page. When you click that button it will go to another method/controller with that path as a parameter and then you could run a force download. There is one more way but it is slightly more complex. Ultimately you have to decide whether you want the image to actually be stored on the server or just processed and have it's contents passed around. I think for you that is the question that needs to be answered first.

Comment: I don't want to store images on server and the button way is lengthy.

Comment: ive updated it to download under "take 2" this is the **only** way that you can download a file that isn't stored on your computer while staying on the same page through all requests